# What algorithm to use to format an EDIFACT file?

Tags: algorithm, methods, process, edifact

I work with EDIFACT messages and have developed lots of tools to help me parse and extract the relevant information out of the raw file format.

Something I have always struggled with is presenting the raw EDIFACT. I typically just copy the message into Microsoft Word, do a find and replace for the segment separator and view the contents line by line.

I have always wanted to display the EDIFACT file in its hierarchy format but can not for the life of me work out a method to do this.

Below is a small extract of a raw EDIFACT message.
The left side shows how I get the data (not including line numbers), the right side shows how I want it to be displayed based on a customers specification.

```
01. UNA                                -UNA
02. UNB                                -UNB
03. UNH                                -UNH 
04. BGM                                -BGM
05. DTM                                - | DTM 
06. DTM                                - | DTM 
07. DTM                                - | DTM
08. NAD                                - | NAD  
09. NAD                                - | NAD
10. NAD                                - | NAD
11. GIS                                - | GIS
12. LIN                                - |  | LIN
13. LOC                                - |  |  | LOC
14. LOC                                - |  |  | LOC
15. LOC                                - |  |  | LOC
16. RFF                                - |  |  | RFF
17. QTY                                - |  |  | QTY  
18. QTY                                - |  |  | QTY
19. RFF                                - |  |  |  | RFF 
20. DTM                                - |  |  |  |  | DTM
21. SCC                                - |  |  | SCC
22. QTY                                - |  |  |  | QTY
23. DTM                                - |  |  |  |  | DTM
24. DTM                                - |  |  |  |  | DTM
25. SCC                                - |  |  | SCC
26. QTY                                - |  |  |  | QTY
27. DTM                                - |  |  |  |  | DTM
28. DTM                                - |  |  |  |  | DTM
29. SCC                                - |  |  | SCC  
30. QTY                                - |  |  |  | QTY
31. DTM                                - |  |  |  |  | DTM
32. QTY                                - |  |  |  | QTY
33. DTM                                - |  |  |  |  | DTM 
34. SCC                                - |  |  | SCC
35. QTY                                - |  |  |  | QTY  
36. DTM                                - |  |  |  |  | DTM  
37. NAD                                - |  |  | NAD
38. CTA                                - |  |  |  | CTA 
39. COM                                - |  |  |  |  | COM
40. SCC                                - |  |  |  | SCC
41. QTY                                - |  |  |  |  | QTY
42. UNT                                -UNT
43. UNZ                                -UNZ
```

You can see that the data is tree based, and it is described by a specification that is sent to me. One specification for the above EDIFACT message is as follow:

```
        Tag    St Max   Lvl
0000 1  UNA    C  1     0 SERVICE STRING ADVICE
0000 2  UNB    M  1     0 INTERCHANGE HEADER
0010 3  UNH    M  1     0 MESSAGE HEADER
0020 4  BGM    M  1     0 BEGINNING OF MESSAGE
0030 5  DTM    M  10    1 DATE/TIME/PERIOD
0040 6  FTX    C  5     1 FREE TEXT
0080    SG2    C  99    1 NAD
0090 7  NAD    M  1     1 NAME AND ADDRESS
0190    SG6    C  9999  1 GIS-SG7-SG12
0200 8  GIS    M  1     1 GENERAL INDICATOR
0210    SG7    C  1     2 NAD
0220 9  NAD    M  1     2 NAME AND ADDRESS
0370    SG12   C  9999  2 LIN-LOC-FTX-SG13-SG15-SG17-SG22
0380 10 LIN    M  1     2 LINE ITEM
0450 11 LOC    C  999   3 PLACE/LOCATION IDENTIFICATION
0470 12 FTX    C  5     3 FREE TEXT
0480    SG13   C  10    3 RFF
0490 13 RFF    M  1     3 REFERENCE
0540    SG15   C  10    3 QTY-SG16
0550 14 QTY    M  1     3 QUANTITY
0570    SG16   C  10    4 RFF-DTM
0580 15 RFF    M  1     4 REFERENCE
0590 16 DTM    C  1     5 DATE/TIME/PERIOD
0600    SG17   C  999   3 SCC-SG18
0610 17 SCC    M  1     3 SCHEDULING CONDITIONS
0620    SG18   C  999   4 QTY-DTM
0630 18 QTY    M  1     4 QUANTITY
0640 19 DTM    C  2     5 DATE/TIME/PERIOD
0760    SG22   C  999   3 NAD-SG24-SG27
0770 20 NAD    M  1     3 NAME AND ADDRESS
0830    SG24   C  5     4 CTA-COM
0840 21 CTA    M  1     4 CONTACT INFORMATION
0850 22 COM    C  5     5 COMMUNICATION CONTACT
0920    SG27   M  999   4 SCC-SG28
0940    SG28   M  999   5 QTY
0950 24 QTY    M  1     5 QUANTITY
1030 25 UNT    M  1     0 MESSAGE TRAILER
0000 26 UNZ    M  1     0 INTERCHANGE TRAILER
```

The important columns are Tag, St (M=Mandatory, C=Conditional), Max (Maximum times it can repeat), lvl (How deep in the tree it is).
The Tags that start with SG denote that there is a loop

The problem I face is that the format is very flexible, where it can have conditional segments, conditional loops, repeated segments. Trying to think of a method that can handle all this has been my issue.

Starting from the top in the above specification, you can immeditely see that when you come to the DTM tag, it can be repeated upto a max of 10 times. In the sample EDIFACT message, it only appears 3 times on lines 5, 6, 7. Following the specification, FTX may appear but does not in my sample message, then there is a SG2 tag, which means the following NAD tag may repeat 99 times.

Moving slightly ahead inside the LIN tag (which is under the SG12 group, which can repeat upto 9999 times and in many cases does repeat a number of times), it comes to the first QTY tag.
According to the specification, this segment can have conditional group (SG15) RFF and a DTM under it. Using my sample, you can see on line 17 and 18 that it has the QTY segment but line 18, has this conditional group too.

Similiar things start happening when you look into the SCC segments too.

What I have in my mind, is to be able to enter that specification into some sort of file format, then run the raw EDIFACT message against the rules of this specification so the output is hierarchy based so it's easy to see at a glance what data relates to what segment and a way to check to see if the EDIFACT message is valid.

What I have trouble with, is the actual algorithm or process to do that conversion.

I have tried naive approaches, like going line by line but then it gets messy when I am trying to work out if the current line is in a group, or a repeat or something else.
I have tried a recursive approach, by splitting the entire EDIFACT by the largest group (The SG12-LIN group), then recursively process each of them splits and build an output. This has been my best approach yet but it's still far from working with many false readings due to my logic not being right.

I basically need to be able to pick a segment of the message, and determine where in the hierarchy it should be and display it.

I am at a loss on how I can solve this. I am sure there is a nice simple method at doing this but I just cannot work it out.

Any assistance would be most grateful.

*Slight update.*

I have converted the specification into a XML file following the hierarchy of said specification. This XML file now contains all the groups and various attributes related to each tag. Now I have a start on what the EDIFACT needs to conform too.

If I go through it on paper (and in head) and I can build the output that I am trying to do with a bit of forward thinking so my new idea is to "Scan ahead" in the EDIFACT file, and build a probably based result.
Bit like how a chess AI looks ahead a few moves.

Comment: I've given you an encouragement upvote, but I'm afraid no generic answer to that problem exists.

Comment: Maybe you can check out the source code for a project that's already done what you want like edivisualizer https://edivisualizer.codeplex.com/

Comment: i've seen some code samples on codeproject that transform EDIFACT messages to XML. I'm no XSD expert, but you could probably validate those converted XML messages with XSD.

Comment: You're going to have to work with a recursive data structure, such as `SGnn=XXX;AAA;BBB;CCC` where XXX is the segment that begins the group and AAA BBB CCC are the member segments. You'll also have to figure how to detect inner segments such as `SGmm=XXX+YYY;DDD;EEE;FFF;GGG` for SGmm found inside SGnn

Comment: @LouisRicci Thanks for that. I seem to have missed that one in my research. Sadly it refuses to open any of my EDIFACT messages and after tweaking the code a bit, I found where it errors but sadly don't know enough about regex to determine what it is trying to do.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek Yes, I have seen plenty of them, and it seems XSD is a common way to validate. Unfortunately I am also no XSD expert so the majority of the code I look at doesn't make much sense. Hence the reason why I have been trying to work it out myself.

Comment: I know that our commercial EDI solution uses generated .NET classes to validate the messages. Essentially the classes are generated from either XSD or an awkward text specification file, after generation they contain a basic validation for max length of strings, max number of segments, mandatory fields etc. I have next to no experience with class generation, so I can't say how complex that is. But it does sort of work...

Answer (score 0):

most of the thing you want I can help you with (and did them). But this is not easy done on a small piece of paper with no interaction. 
So if you want more information, just contact me.  (no, this is not a commercial  thing)